# window.ScrollMaxY or X - How to set in FireFox 3?

Tags: javascript, firefox

window.scrollMaxY can be set via that property in IE and older versions of Firefox, but when trying in FF3 it says "Cannot set this property as it only has a getter".

What is my alternative?

EDIT:

The reason why I'm asking is that I'm fixing some very horrible JS written by someone else, it has a function to keep a div centered on the page while scrolling, and has this line:

```
// Fixes Firefox incrementing page height while scrolling
window.scrollMaxY = scrollMaxY
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but the main issue is that when the page is scrolled, it grows in length.

Answer (score 1):

> window.scrollMaxY can be set via that property in IE and older versions of Firefox

I don't see that this exists in IE at all.

If i try to modify it in FF3 *before reading its value*, then i am able to do so, although changing it has no visible effects.

If i assign a value to it prior to accessing its value, i'm able to do so. Once i've successfully assigned a value to it, i can query and modify its value as much as i like, though the browser will no longer update it to reflect the actual scroll limit of the window - this behavior would appear to exist for compatibility with code that might use this variable name in other browsers, not expecting it to be pre-defined.

What would you expect modifying it to do?

(testing in IE6 / FF3, answer revised to note pre-query vs post-query behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you are looking for is different CSS. Instead of trying to bend the browser to fit the HTML, it would be easier to find a better solution for the actual problem; keeping the div in place.

To position elements relative to the window use `position: fixed;`

My guess is that the code you are looking at was originally a workaround for the lack of [support for fixed positioning](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t117) (IE6 doesn't support it).